# Does a delayed refund suggest that an audit is likely?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, income-tax-refund, audit

My US federal tax refund is taking an unusually long time to be issued this year. I e-filed my return 3.5 months ago and the IRS Refund Status page just says it is "still being processed".

[The IRS has announced that certain types of 2020 returns are taking longer to process](https://www.irs.gov/refunds/tax-season-refund-frequently-asked-questions), such as those which claim an Earned Income Tax Credit or Additional Child Tax Credit.  However, none of those criteria apply to my return as far as I know.  I didn't claim any of those credits, I e-filed using mainstream software, I have no history of tax-related identity theft or fraud, and I believe my return was complete.  So the only item on that list that could apply is "Needs further review in general" which sounds ominous.

I do have some reason to think my return might be audited, as I deducted a rather large amount for charitable contributions (yes, I have all the receipts).  Should I interpret the delayed refund as a sign that I should get ready for an audit, or is it probably just unrelated?

The answer to [When does the IRS generally decide whether or not to audit your tax return?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/29260/when-does-the-irs-generally-decide-whether-or-not-to-audit-your-tax-return) say that receiving your refund *on time* doesn't imply that you *won't* be audited, but I am not sure if the converse also holds.  That answer is also 7 years old and IRS procedures could have changed.